# get the maximum element in an array using "=="

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array `x` :

```
numpy.random.seed(1)
#input
x = numpy.arange(0.,20.,1)
x = x.reshape(5,4)
print(x)

[[ 0.  1.  2.  3.]
 [ 4.  5.  6.  7.]
 [ 8.  9. 10. 11.]
 [12. 13. 14. 15.]
 [16. 17. 18. 19.]]
```

I want to access the maximum element in this array. In my assignment, the answer has this line to access the maximum one in `x` :

```
print(x[x==x.max()])
[19.]
```

I search documentation but found only one way of accessing the maximum element using `argmax`. I don't find the way of using "`==`" in the documentation, so I don't understand how this works. Can anyone explain why this works and show where it is in the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called **Boolean array indexing**.

With `x == x.max()`, the below boolean array is generated:

```py
[[ False  False  False  False]
 [ False  False  False  False]
 [ False  False  False  False]
 [ False  False  False  False]
 [ False  False  False  True]]
```

Then with `x[x==x.max()]`, the above array is used as a mask to filter the elements of `x` that correspond to the `True`.

#### Reference:

https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing

Answer (score 2):

This is using a boolean mask array. Here's the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays).

What you're doing is you're producing a boolean array, then using that as a mask to index into your original array:

```py
# x == x.max()
[[ False  False  False  False]
 [ False  False  False  False]
 [ False  False  False  False]
 [ False  False  False  False]
 [ False  False  False  True]]
```

Comment: @user14416085 Here is another relevant piece of documentation: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing Your original code is basically saying "Create an array with all the elements in the original array that are equal to the maximum element in the original array".